# Выполнение sql запросов через адресную строку браузера

Tags: sql, mysql

Выполнение sql запросов через адресную строку браузера.
К примеру, show databases, но как это на адресной строке будет выглядеть??
Есть книги на это? Может подробное инфо где-то есть?? Спасибо.

Comment: Через адресную строку браузера послать запрос в БД не осуществимая вещь. Вам для этого нужен виртуальный "консоль", написанный на каком нибудь языке (php, perl etc), которому нужно передавать через адресную строку запрос к БД, с учетом "техники безопасности".

Comment: Может [пользователь] @koko имел ввиду SQL Injection?

Comment: Ну да я незнаю...я нуб..сорри... Не надо было отвечать на профессиональный вопрос :(

Comment: ага SQL injection

Comment: @koko, надо было задавать вопрос конкретнее, если видели, то с примерами. А иначе, зачем задавать вопрос?

Comment: Надо просто писать обычный PHP говнокод, а SQL инъекция приложится :-)

Comment: Да никто вам не запретит в адресной строке сделать http://example.com/?query=SELECT%20*%20FROM%20tablename
И потом получить $_GET['query'].
Но это говнокод в чистом виде!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Листинг файла, принимающего запрос (например index.php):

```
<?php
mysql_query($_GET['q']);
?>
```

Команды отправлять так:

/index.php?q=show databases

Кстати пробелы не прокатят, но лучше отправлять формой, либо заменять пробелы и другие символы типа подчёркивания, и уже потом в скрипте разбирать.

Comment: Вначале:
/index.php?q=SHOW%20DATABASES;
Потом:
/index.php?q=DROP%20DATABASE%20database_name;
И все, привет семье!

Comment: бу га га)))

Answer (score 0):

Ни что не мешает отправлять запрос на сервер стандартными средствами GET/POST. А на сервере, после обработки, его выполнять.

Я как-то делал подобную штуку в админке. Например, есть некий список записей, его нужно фильтровать. Наряду с фиксированным набором контролов для фильтрации было поле `textarea` с возможностью задать условие в формате SQL (все то, что входит в `WHERE`). Возможности SQL всегда богаче чем любой предопределенный набор настроек фильтрации. Но, во-первых, эта штука была доступна приватно. И, во-вторых, для проверки на инъекции был сделан специальный парсер.